# Absence of matter stretches the fabric of space?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-constant

If matter attracts matter, because it curves the space, could it be that the absence of matter stretches the space,
and that's why the universe expansion is accelerating?

I mean that could be something that we don't know yet
in the fabric of space that the absence of matter causes it to stretch.

Is there some research in this sense already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a term in Einstein's GR that is called the cosmological constant and it describes a cosmological force or pressure that is entirely due to the presence of spacetime. Usually this force/pressure is referred to by its coupling constant, $\Lambda$, the cosmological constant. I regard this as a bit unfortunate as its like referring to gravity by referring to $G$, the gravitational constant, and the coupling constant for gravity rather than the manifestation of gravity as a force.

The cosmological force tends to accelerate the expansion of the universe. Recently observations have confirmed this acceleration and modern cosmological theory assigns it a small positive value. If the universe is infinite, which can only be discovered empirically, as Einstein's equations doesn't rule out such a possibility, then the limit of the observable universe is where spacetime is accelerating at speeds faster than that of light.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That pointed me the way to study more.

Comment: I was wondering if there would be something similar to the Higgs Boson (that "causes" gravity);  some particle involved in this repulsion.

Comment: @Jose Renato: You're welcome. Look up the inflaton for the conjectured particle driving inflation and which arises from the cosmological force. Also note the gravition which is the conjectured particle of the gravitational field.

Comment: This is interesting! Best regards!